# Get attribute names and values from ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xmlroot

I have an XML `<root>` element with several attributes. I've been using the `ElementTree` package.

After I've parsed a tree from an xml file, I'm getting the document root, but I want to get the requested attribute, or even the entire list of attributes.

```
<root a="1" b="2" c="3">
    </blablabla>
</root>
```

How can I retrieve all attribute names and values for a `<root>` element with ElementTree?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Each `Element` has an attribute `.attrib` that is a dictionary; simply use it's [mapping methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to ask it for it's keys or values:

```
for name, value in root.attrib.items():
    print '{0}="{1}"'.format(name, value)
```

or

```
for name in root.attrib:
    print '{0}="{1}"'.format(name, root.attrib[name])
```

or use `.values()` or any of the other methods available on a python `dict`.

To get an individual attribute, use the standard [subscription syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions):

```
print root.attrib['a']
```

Answer (score 9):

The `attrib` attribute of an ElementTree element (like the root returned by `getroot`) is a dictionary.  So you can do, for example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print root.attrib
```

which will output, for your example

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some nice loop you can use it will get for each element of the xmlObject it's tag, text and attribute
it will work for 2 levels XML, it's not the best way to iterate but it can be useful for simple things...

```
for headTag in xmlObject.getchildren():
    print headTag.tag, headTag.text, headTag.attrib
    for bodyTag in headTag.getchildren():
        print "\t", bodyTag.tag, bodyTag.text, bodyTag.attrib
```