# Storing value from XML as variable with Python

Tags: python, xml

I want to store a value from an XML file as a variable in Python to use it for calculations later on. The value shall be the speed of sound.
The XML file contains different types of liquid mediums, temperature and speed of sounds.
I am loading the XML file with etree.

```
root = ET.parse(folder_path2+filename8)
SoS = root.find('.//SpeedofSound')
tree = ET.parse(folder_path2+filename8)
root = tree.getroot()
for SoS in root.findall('SpeedofSound'):
```

The XML looks like this:

<Medium="Water" SpeedofSound=" 1480" Temperature=" 15"/>

I come up to this point, but then I don't know how to store it as a variable.

Thanks.

!!!SOLVED!!!

I did it this way:

```
SoS = df["SpeedofSound"].dropna().to_numpy()
```

The value is stored and I can also use it for other calculations.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Please post a [mcve] with code and XML as text (not as an image).

Comment: I corrected my post.

Comment: Even though that is not well-formed XML, it appears that you have an element with a `SpeedofSound=" 1480"` attribute and that you want to store the 1480 value in a variable.

Comment: Exactly, I want to store it as SoS and use it for further calculations. My calculations are working when I put in the value manually in the code for SoS

Comment: Anybody who can help here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14323335/407651

Comment: I finish now with print(SoS.attribute), but I always get the error that SoS is not defined

Comment: The XML is an output from a different software and I cannot change it. However, I found now a solution: df = pd.read_xml(folder_path2+filename8)
SoS = df["SpeedofSound"].dropna().to_numpy()